# Hypercube of chain complexes as functor from (Δ^1 )^n to ∞-category of chain complexes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, infinity-categories, chain-complexes, hypercube

A hypercube of chain complexes consists of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded vector spaces $C_\epsilon$ for $\epsilon\in\{0,1\}^n$ and maps $D_{\epsilon,\epsilon^\prime}:C_{\epsilon}\to C_{\epsilon^\prime}$ for $\epsilon,\epsilon^\prime$ with each component $\epsilon[i]\le\epsilon^\prime[i]$ for $i\in[1,n]$ (we write $\epsilon\le \epsilon^\prime$). Moreover, those maps shift the gradings by $|\epsilon-\epsilon^\prime|_{L_1}-1$ and satisfy $\sum_{\epsilon\le \delta\le\epsilon^\prime}D_{\delta,\epsilon^\prime}\circ D_{\epsilon,\delta}=0$ for any $\epsilon\le \epsilon^\prime$.

Can we regard the hypercube of chain complexes as a functor from the simplicial set  $(\Delta^1 )^n$ to $\infty$-category of chain complexes?

In particular, when $n=2$, the hypercube corresponds to commutative diagram up to homotopy if we add signs for maps properly. Can we regard such diagram as a functor from $\Delta^1\times\Delta^1$ to $\infty$-category of chain complexes?

Comment: The main thing I get confused is that for $n=2$, there are five nondegenerate 1-simplices and two nondegenerate 2-simplices in $\Delta^1\times\Delta^1$ (Example 3.6 in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/product+of+simplices), but in a commutative diagram there is only four edge maps and one homotopy fills the square.

Comment: Apropos your comment, keep in mind that since our base "shape" is a triangle, we encode a square in simplicial sets as a pair of triangles which share a long edge. The result is a square being encoded by 5 edges forming two triangles as you mentioned above.

Comment: Unfortunately I think "if we add signs for maps properly" is the crux of this question. A cubical diagram in the dg-nerve of the category of complexes will construct data fairly similar to this with some extra redundant information. Whether the formula you write can be made to match up with the corresponding sign change will probably require some work.